# Drag behavior returning NaN in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have this code:

```
  var stage = d3.select("body").append("svg");
  var points = [0, 50, 100, 150];
  var letters = "drag".split(",");
  var log = d3.select("#log");

  //drag behaviour, will bind later
    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(Object)
      .on("drag", dragmove);


  //append texts
    var texts = stage
        .selectAll("text")
        .data(letters)
        .enter()
            .append("text")
            .attr("font-family", "Arial")
            .attr("class", "word")
            .attr("x", function(d,i){return points[i]})
            .attr("y", 100)
            .text(function(d){return d})
            .call(drag);

    function dragmove() {
        log.text(
            "x: " + d3.event.x + ", " +
            "y: " + d3.event.y + ", " +
            "dx: " + d3.event.dx + ", " +
            "dy: " + d3.event.dy
            );
        d3.select(this).attr("x", d3.event.x);
    }​
```

However, `d3.event.x` and `d3.event.y` are returning `NaN`. Funnily enough, `d3.event.dx` and `d3.event.dy` are returning the right values. What is wrong with my code?

You can see a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UMwmr/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because `d3.event` relay to data, if you check in your code that:

```
.attr("x", function(d,i){console.log(d);return points[i]})
```

you will find that d is text, which can't have x,y properties.

the solution is to make each letter as object (you also splitted them by "," but i gues it should be "" ) so here the code:

```
var stage = d3.select("body").append("svg");
var points = [0, 50, 100, 150];
var letters = "drag".split("").map(function(d, i) {
    return {
        text: d,
        x: points[i],
        y: 100
    }
});
var log = d3.select("#log");

//drag behaviour, will bind later
var drag = d3.behavior
    .drag()
    .origin(Object)
    .on("drag", dragmove);


//append texts
var texts = stage
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(letters)
    .enter()
       .append("text")
       .attr("font-family", "Arial")
       .attr("class", "word")
       .attr("x", function(d, i) {
            return d.x;
       })
       .attr("y", 100)
       .text(function(d) {
            return d.text;
           })
       .call(drag);

function dragmove(d) {
    log.text(
        "x: " + d3.event.x + ", " + 
        "y: " + d3.event.y + ", " + 
        "dx: " + d3.event.dx + ", " + 
        "dy: " + d3.event.dy);
    //set new position to the object
    d.x=d3.event.x;
    d3.select(this).attr("x", d3.event.x);
}​
```

and [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/UMwmr/3/)

Comment: Just to add to this. It is the drag.origin that requires the (x,y) position to be bound as data to the DOM element. If you would comment out the .origin(Object) in the original code it would not give NaNs (but still would have some other problems) https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior#wiki-origin